# Truncate HTML to certain length of RENDERED characters

Tags: javascript, html

I'm receiving some HTML with an arbitrary number of  tags that I need to truncate in order to fit within 25 characters, however I don't want to leave any open tags.

For example, if I receive `blah blah blah <a href="#">supercalifragilistic</a>` I need to truncate it to something like `blah blah blah <a href="#">superc...</a>` rather than `blah blah blah <a href="#">supercal...`

My best thoughts right now are to use javascript to strip and then reapply the tags after truncation, or to put it all in a div and hide overflow. Not sure what the best option is or if there's an even simpler one.

Thanks!

Comment: Hiding the overflow is definitely a simpler option. Now whether it works for you depends on your requirements (obviously the cut will be arbitrary, not the 25 characters you're expecting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this JQuery plugin: http://thepugautomatic.com/octopress/2008/02/jquery-html-truncate/

Had to edit the code a little bit to get it to do what I want, but it works. Unfortunately it's a little slower than I'd prefer, but still good for many cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would start off with `userInput.length` to return how many characters you actually received.